# Как удалить кружок из QRadioButton и оставить только букву?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qss

Мой код

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RadioButton(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RadioButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.toggled.connect(self.change_text)
        self.setObjectName(u"rb0")
        self.setText('W')


    def change_text(self):
        if self.isChecked():                                   
            self.setText('C')
        else:
            self.setText('W')

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(30, 30)      


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            
            'rb0': False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))


        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.main_layout)


        self.rb0 = RadioButton()                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'
        self.rb0.setStyleSheet('QRadioButton{background: red} QRadioButton::indicator {width:0 ;height:0;}')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.rb1.setObjectName(u"rb1")



        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.rb2.setObjectName(u"rb2")
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 

        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')
        self.rb3.setObjectName(u"rb3")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         

        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.objectName()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.objectName()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)              
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.objectName()] = True

        print("Нажата кнопка -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.objectName(), radioButton.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне нужно удалить кружок и центрировать букву по середине 
Но проблема в том что я не могу полностью удалить кружок
когда я пишу

```
 QRadioButton::indicator {width:0 ;height:0;}
```

консоль выдает

> QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И QRadioButton не реагирует на setAlignment и text-align.

Я пробовал использовать QSizePolicy

```
    sizePolicy0 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy0.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy0.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy0.setHeightForWidth(self.rb0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.rb0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy0)

    sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.rb1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.rb1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)

    sizePolicy2 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy2.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.rb2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.rb2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)

    sizePolicy3 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy3.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy3.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy3.setHeightForWidth(self.rb3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.rb3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy3)
```

Но получилось как то не очень

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовав

```
  QRadioButton::indicator {background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); width:1 ;height:1;}
```

Я смог полностью скрыть кнопку но одступ остался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что бы удалить одступ я использовал padding-left:-5;
Это не самый лучший способ но другого я не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Я не получаю никаких сообщений на консоль.

Чуть-чуть подправил таблицу стилей.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RadioButton(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RadioButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.toggled.connect(self.change_text)
        self.setObjectName(u"rb0")
        self.setText('W')

    def change_text(self):
        if self.isChecked():                                   
            self.setText('C')
        else:
            self.setText('W')

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(30, 30)      


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            
            'rb0': False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.rb0 = RadioButton()                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.rb1.setObjectName(u"rb1")

        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.rb2.setObjectName(u"rb2")
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 

        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')
        self.rb3.setObjectName(u"rb3")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.objectName()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.objectName()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)              
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.objectName()] = True

        print("Нажата кнопка -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.objectName(), radioButton.isChecked()))
        # print(f"... -> `{self.rb0.width()} - {self.rb0.height()}`")


StyleSheet = '''
QRadioButton#rb0 {
    background: red;
    color: #eff0f1;
    font-weight: bold;
} 
QRadioButton::indicator#rb0 {
    width: 35;                        /* <<<-------< */
    height:0;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня код выводит ошибку QPainter каждый раз когда я навожу мышку на кнопку.

Comment: И центрирование должно быть автоматическим а не писать постоянно `width: 35`